# how to mount partitions from USB drives in Windows using Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, usb

I want to mount all partitions from USB drives in Windows (XP). I mean I want to assign to each of them drive letters (when they don't have one).
The OS is doing this automatically but there are situations when such a program is useful.

I know how to find if a drive is on USB or not.
My code so far is:

```
type
   STORAGE_QUERY_TYPE = (PropertyStandardQuery = 0, PropertyExistsQuery, PropertyMaskQuery, PropertyQueryMaxDefined);
   TStorageQueryType = STORAGE_QUERY_TYPE;

   STORAGE_PROPERTY_ID = (StorageDeviceProperty = 0, StorageAdapterProperty);
   TStoragePropertyID = STORAGE_PROPERTY_ID;

   STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY = packed record
      PropertyId: STORAGE_PROPERTY_ID;
      QueryType: STORAGE_QUERY_TYPE;
      AdditionalParameters: array[0..9] of AnsiChar;
   end;
   TStoragePropertyQuery = STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY;

   STORAGE_BUS_TYPE = (BusTypeUnknown = 0, BusTypeScsi, BusTypeAtapi, BusTypeAta, BusType1394, BusTypeSsa, BusTypeFibre,
      BusTypeUsb, BusTypeRAID, BusTypeiScsi, BusTypeSas, BusTypeSata, BusTypeMaxReserved = $7F);
   TStorageBusType = STORAGE_BUS_TYPE;

   STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR = packed record
      Version: DWORD;
      Size: DWORD;
      DeviceType: Byte;
      DeviceTypeModifier: Byte;
      RemovableMedia: Boolean;
      CommandQueueing: Boolean;
      VendorIdOffset: DWORD;
      ProductIdOffset: DWORD;
      ProductRevisionOffset: DWORD;
      SerialNumberOffset: DWORD;
      BusType: STORAGE_BUS_TYPE;
      RawPropertiesLength: DWORD;
      RawDeviceProperties: array[0..0] of AnsiChar;
   end;
   TStorageDeviceDescriptor = STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR;

const
   IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY = $002D1400;   

var i: Integer;
   H: THandle;
   USBDrives: array of Byte;
   Query: TStoragePropertyQuery;
   dwBytesReturned: DWORD;
   Buffer: array[0..1023] of Byte;
   sdd: TStorageDeviceDescriptor absolute Buffer;   

begin
   SetLength(UsbDrives, 0);
   SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
   for i := 0 to 99 do
   begin
      H := CreateFile(PChar('\\.\PhysicalDrive' + IntToStr(i)), 0, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
      if H <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
      begin
         try
            dwBytesReturned := 0;
            FillChar(Query, SizeOf(Query), 0);
            FillChar(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), 0);
            sdd.Size := SizeOf(Buffer);
            Query.PropertyId := StorageDeviceProperty;
            Query.QueryType := PropertyStandardQuery;
            if DeviceIoControl(H, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, @Query, SizeOf(Query), @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), dwBytesReturned, nil) then
               if sdd.BusType = BusTypeUsb then
               begin
                  SetLength(USBDrives, Length(USBDrives) + 1);
                  UsbDrives[High(USBDrives)] := Byte(i);
               end;
         finally
            CloseHandle(H);
         end;
      end;
   end;
   for i := 0 to High(USBDrives) do
   begin
     //
   end;
end.
```

But I don't know how to access partitions on each drive and mounts them.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the volume management functions - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

FirstFirstVolume, FindNextVolume, FindVolumeClose will list off the partitions as \\?\Volume{Guid} names.

Createfile should be able to option the volume names so your code above can check it's USB.

SetVolumeMountPoint lets you mount a Volume as a drive letter or a folder mount point.

This blog entry talks about Volume names - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2005/04/16/408947.aspx

Comment: Seems like a good idea. Thank you. But I have 2 problems: 1. On my computer it finds the total number of partitions minus one. For example my internal HDD has 4, it finds 3 (instead of 4). I add a USB stick to the computer (with a single partition), it finds 4 (instead of 5). 2. When I pass this names to CreateFile it returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE; GetLastError says ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND. What should I do?

Comment: I solved the second problem by removing '\' at the end of each name

Comment: Oh, I understand now: FirstFirstVolume, FindNextVolume, FindVolumeClose does not find hidden partitions (2 of 4 are hidden). So the solution is good :) Sorry that I can't vote you yet :(

Comment: @vickd A question: I am not ungrateful, you helped me a lot. But is there another way to mount partitions? I ask because on some computers FindFirstVolume, FindNextVolume and FindVolumeClose can't find some volumes. You can see the physical drive in Disk Management, you can mount the partitions manually but those functions can't find them. Can you please help me again...? Thank you.

Comment: DefineDosDevice can mount using device names.  Rather than use PhysicalDisk0..99, try \Device\Harddisk0..99\Partition1..4  If you get a handle, then use DefineDosDevice(1, 'J:', '\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1')  (changing J and \device as appropriate).  DefineDosDevice (2, 'J', nil) will unmount it.

Comment: Run WinObj.exe to see if the partitions you want are in the Windows object manager (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657).  If they are you could interrogate that but you have to use native Nt API (ansi example here: http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_1184.asp?SK=  -- ntdll.pas is available here http://home.earthlink.net/~akonshin/delphi_components.htm), though it may be easier to stick with the drive/partition numbers in a loop if that approach isn't an issue.

Comment: @vickd I tried this: "H := CreateFile(PChar(String('\Device\Harddisk' + IntToStr(i) + '\Partition' + IntToStr(j))), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);" The problem is that H is always invalid and GetLastError returns ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Are the volumes not visible on the first insertion of the usb or subsequent tries too?  Is there anything special/different about them in disk manager that may explain?  You could try the following.  Use QueryDosDevice to get the mounted device names for each letter (query C:, get \Device\HarddiskVolume1).  Run DefineDosDevice(1, 'X:', '\Device\HarddiskVolume'+IntToStr(i)) for each volume that isn't already mapped.  Check the return from DefineDosDevice to see if it worked and advance the letter.  Did you run winobj on the machines?  If the devices aren't listed there this won't work either.

Comment: There's examples of WMI queries for accessing drives here: http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/disk/drives/  but the mount one uses volumes so may not work either if that can't see the new volumes.  You can get the partition info for a drive via DeviceIOControl using IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO.  Long shot - may be calling IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_PROPERTIES would cause the volume manager to refresh and give the partitions a volume id?

Comment: @wickd Yes and no. Yes, on those machines the volumes are not visible on the insertion of the usb. No, are visible on my computer where I tested CreateFile. Regardind what you said I should try: the problem is that the USB sticks are seen as "\Device\Hardisk1\...". And it's worst: the first partition on one of my sticks is seen as "\Device\Hardisk1\DP(1)0-0+6". A few hours ago I thought at something similar but it's very difficult to connect QueryDosDevice with DefineDosDevice (especially to make it work on any computer).

Comment: I thought at other solution: I use DefineDosDevice to map any "\Device\HardDisk[0..49]\Partition[1..]"; if GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint can get Volume name then I erase the mount point because that device was already mapped by the OS. This way works for the USB storage devices. The problem is that it mappes also hidden partitions... So I still don't have a solution...

Comment: For your second message: WMI is not working well on those machines. And I thought too at those 2: IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO is good but how can I use the results; IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_PROPERTIES is used by DeviceIoControl who needs the handle of the partition; but where can I find this handle...?